# include header.php css, wont work on include footer.php or the body

Tags: php, html, css

I am attempting to `require '_header.php';` and `require '_footer.php';` so I can create a dynamic body for my site.

However none of the CSS will work in the body or in the footer. CSS will only work for the header.

Why is this happening and how could it be solved?

```
require '_header.php';



$form_to_echo = '<div class="form_wrap"><form id="registration" action="new_user.php" method="post">                                                                

    <div class="i_group"><span class="s_name">Класа:</span> 
    <input type="radio" id="_rad_rnk_class_h" name="rank_class" value="H"'.$_frm_selected_rank_class_h.'><label for="_rad_rnk_class_h">Хоби</label>
    <input type="radio" id="_rad_rnk_class_t" name="rank_class" value="T"'.$_frm_selected_rank_class_t.'><label for="_rad_rnk_class_t">Трофеј</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="cell_phone" name="cell_number" placeholder="Мобилен телефон" value="'.$_POST['cell_number'].'">
    </div>  

    <div class="i_group"><span class="s_name">Крвна група:</span><br><br>                               
    <input type="radio" id="_rad_bld_typ_a" name="blood_type" value="A"'.$_frm_selected_bld_typ_a.'><label for="_rad_bld_typ_a">A</label>
    <input type="radio" id="_rad_bld_typ_b" name="blood_type" value="B"'.$_frm_selected_bld_typ_b.'><label for="_rad_bld_typ_b">B</label>
    <input type="radio" id="_rad_bld_typ_ab" name="blood_type" value="AB"'.$_frm_selected_bld_typ_ab.'><label for="_rad_bld_typ_ab">AB</label>
    <input type="radio" id="_rad_bld_typ_o" name="blood_type" value="O"'.$_frm_selected_bld_typ_o.'><label for="_rad_bld_typ_o">O</label>
    </div>                                      
    <div class="i_group">               
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Pегистрирај">
    </div></form></div>';


if ($error_count_up != 0) { 

    echo $form_to_echo; 

}

require '_footer.php';
```

---

When I copy and paste the code in HTML it works just fine...

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <head lang="mk">
        <meta charset="utf-8">


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <title>;</title>
        <style type="text/css">

</style>



               <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
               <!--<script src="script.js"></script> -->


                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
                  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
                  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                  <script>
                        $( function() {
                            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                                changeMonth: true,
                                changeYear: true
                            });
                        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );
                        } );
                  </script>

    </head>





    <body>      



        <div id="showcase">


            <div id="sw_img1"></div>
            <div class="img_fade"></div>

                <div class="main_wrapper">

                    <div id="logo"></div>


                    <ul id="top_nav">

                        <li>Правилник</li>

                        <li>Контакт</li>    

                    </ul>


                </div>

        </div>
```

---

```
        <div class="test1">test</div>






    </body>





</html>
```

Comment: it's better to share the content of header and footer too, and make the question more clear. I cant understand what is "CSS wont work"..

Comment: @tazotodua CSS wont work = no styling is applied to anything after the header. You can see the `header.php` and `footer.php` code as well.

Comment: Use base_url for your css file references so you don't have problems when using them as a theme

Comment: If the code and header.php are not under the same folder, header will try to access a folder above, from the same folder as the calling script is.

Comment: Are you sure the html code that you copy and paste is the same as the html code the php creates? Try this: Use the php method and copy all of the content. Then copy and past html and compare the output of php with the output of html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using include...
[PHP: include](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)

Comment: I've tried. No effect. I also tried `echo file_get_contents()`

Comment: Yes. And again...the CSS works for the header.php file but not for the html `echo $form_to_echo; ` or for anything in the footer. Could it have something to do with php7?

Answer (score 0):

you use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

so, `style.css` should be in the same folder where the URL is executed (not where the .php file is placed)

for example, if you visit 'example.com/dir1/dir2/mypage.html`then`style.css`should be in`dir2`

i advice to use the root urls for styles,scripts, images, like this:

```
..........................  href='/style.css' .........
```

and put `style.css` in root `example.com/` folder.